# What exactly is a “network boundary?”

Tags: networking, terminology

The term “network boundary” is used in various Wikipedia articles and other sources, but I haven’t found an explicit definition anywhere.  (Google, Stack Exchange, OneLook, Tech Terms Computer Dictionary, Computer Hope, etc…)

I can take it as the general English meaning of the word “boundary” combined with the word “network,” but given its presence in numerous precision definitions and explanations, the lack of a distinct definition with examples is bothersome.

Example sentences:

> The Internet Protocol (IP) is the principal communications protocol in
>   the Internet protocol suite for relaying datagrams across network
>   boundaries.

Another:

> We wouldn’t have to cross a network boundary to get…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, "network" is synonymous with "LAN" or local area network. It is by definition a realm of connected machines that can communicate using the [OSI Data Link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_2:_Data_Link_Layer) (layer 2). A machine that is not directly connected to your LAN is outside your network boundary, and you cannot contact it.

In the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) the internet is an Internetwork, a system of interconnected networks, which is implemented by a common protocol which operates at [OSI layer 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_3:_Network_Layer), and allows the use of [Routers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_%28computing%29), which convey traffic from LAN to LAN as the datagrams cross the internetwork. IP is an Internetwork layer protocol, so it can use routers to relay traffic as your example sentence explains.

Comment: After writing my own answer, I re-considered and decided the existing answers provide right answers, & we needn't another answer to vote on. <BLOCKQUOTE>I can take it as the general English meaning of the word “boundary” combined with the word “network,”</BLOCKQUOTE> is absolutely right. Like the word “group”, a “network” could use different criteria. (Think of groups of people, males, boys, or fast boys. Now, how big is a “group”?) The reason why it seems like there's ambiguity is that the word “network” can have some flexibility to it. But a linked net (LAN)/subnet is consistent w/ examples.

Comment: Well, I think Jake's answer is perfectly valid in the correct context. Since Ops first quote describes IP, My answer is correct contextually, but not necessarily the only valid answer to the general question "what does network boundary mean?". if we want to get etymological about it, the word boundary is chosen to represent a barrier or wall that represents the extent of a capability (in this case, the capability to communicate). The term originates from before the Internet, when the only kinds of networks were LANs.

Comment: Your answer looks good *now*.  It was only partially clear when I first read it and was just learning about these things.  I think the key point here is that "network" has more than one meaning and in this case means, without getting into complex terminology, "a set of directly connected computers."  The word "directly" here means *roughly* "physically (connected) without passing through relays (though switches are okay)".  But that is good enough to understand "network boundary" whereas the definition of network "a set of connected computers that can talk to each other" is insufficient.

Comment: Great! yes that is the traditional definition of "network" from the old days when there was no Internet (eg 1954 - 1975 or so) and WAN links, if they existed were point-to-point trunks provided by the telephone company by physically connecting a circuit between both locations. Back then there were no layer3 protocols (not until NCP, and then IP).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that a “network boundary” is a logical construct. Meaning, I would take it to mean the “network boundary” is the difference between what a system can physically connect to versus what network resources they are logically able to access on a network.

For example, if I connect to a LAN via Wi-Fi or a physical cable, but the network is restricted via MAC address and my device’s MAC address is not granted entry, the “boundary” of that network would simply be my the literal edge of that routing device. That router sees my connection, allows my connection but then says, “Nope, no further for you…”

Similarly the network boundary between—let’s say—a WAN or a LAN could be defined as: WAN traffic begins and ends at the router for inbound traffic unless ports are opened on the router to allow further access. And on a related note, systems connected via the LAN themselves are assigned IP addresses within the range that router can handle and nothing else. Thus port forwarding on a router from the WAN to a LAN system bridges the network boundary.