# Why using a proxy server prevents accessing to local addresses?

Tags: networking, dns, proxy

I wasn't able to reach a local address. I have searched the web and eventually learned that I have to turn off the proxy server (or add exception sites) in order to access local addresses.

However, I could not understand why is this happening. AFAIK, when you request to access to an address, domain name translation must take place, whether or not you have requested a local address or an internet address.

Could you explain why we need to bypass the proxy server when we want to access to a local address? What are the steps in this process?

Comment: Please describe your network. Your title indicates you understand the differances between local and public addresses, so I'm not sure why you are having trouble understanding LAN and WAN, or what routers are/do.

Comment: @FrankThomas Problem is, I don't know much about my network. I am at work and don't extensively know how the network is. I know about local vs public IP adresses but I don't understand why I cannot access to a local IP once my request is sent to a proxy server. I feel like since my request was sent to proxy server, then my computer and proxy server are on the same network and hence, I feel like both must be able to see devices on this network.

Comment: its not you who cannot access your local IP, it is the proxy server that cannot. You are inside a LAN, and a router connects your LAN to other LANs that are part of the internet. your Router will let you send requests for service out to Internet servers, and those servers can respond, but only if you made the request; if you don't make a request your router will block them from connecting to you. this is for security purposes. In this case, a proxy actually has TWO connections, one from you, and one to the remote destination, so it is not a response, and your router blocks the proxy incoming.

Comment: A Note on terminology, A LAN is a Network, but a WAN/CAN/MAN are Internetworks, not networks. So you can connect to servers that are not on the same LAN/Network you are, as long as both your LAN and the remote LAN are part of the same Internetwork. You can connect to the remote Proxy server over the Internet, but it cannot connect back to you, because your LAN implements Stateful Packet Filtering, and NAT, which prevent unsolicited incoming connection attempts, and from a TCP perspective, that is exactly what the Proxy server is trying to do.

Comment: @FrankThomas So the reason proxy server doen't see the devices on my network is because the proxy is not in my network right? That is: I must be accessing it with a NATing router?

Comment: That appears to be the case. It is possible that the proxy is on the gateway of your network, and its interfaces are not correctly configured to proxy connections inbound (so essentially the same issue), but theres no real differance either way. by adding the internal site to the proxy exception list, the request will just go right to the LAN server, without passing through the proxy.

Comment: @FrankThomas Ah I see. Thank you very much. By the way, regarding the LAN server point: I was going to ask how a request like: `http://<insert local computer name here>` is directed to the correct computer? That is, I think that still a name resolution is required right? But I think that mapping info is stored in the LAN server. Is that really the case?

Comment: Yes name resolution is necessary, before the packets are created. by the time the packets are created and sent, that name has already been turned into an IP address. It is possible that the HTTP proxy command sequences (specifically the CONNECT verb) might use a DNS name, and that name may not always be accessible, that is correct. to test, point the browser to HTTP://<IPaddress> and if it connects, but fails when you put in a domain name, it is a name resolution issue

Comment: @FrankThomas But is there a way to know where the name resolution is performed? For example, can I know whether the name resolution is performed on my computer or on the LAN server? (Or maybe somewhere else?)

Comment: Not without sniffing traffic to capture the command text inside the packets. Either way, NS resolution is a less likely problem given your description.

Answer (score 1):

It's a routing problem (to state it in a simple manner). When you configure a proxy server, you're instructing your browser to send all the web connections to a unique ip (the proxy). The proxy server receives the connection request but if it's addressed to a private IP (internal address) it will fail.
As you say, the options are adding an exception (you can use wildcards, like 10.* or *.your.domain).

Comment: But why doesn't the proxy see the internal addresses?

Answer (score 0):

> Could you explain why we need to bypass the proxy server when we want to access to a local address?

Note: There are a couple assumptions/generalizations made here due to lack of specifics in OP...

1. The proxy is external to your local network, so it has no idea about where to find it or how to communicate with it (even if it could, your firewall most likely blocks incoming public requests).
2. When you tell your browser/OS to send all traffic via the proxy, then it *all goes to the proxy first*.  So for all traffic bound for local hosts, the proxy has no idea where to send it (see 1), so it fails.

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I wanted to ask: 1) What does it mean to be _external_? Could you explain that more? 2) If it was internal, could it be able to resolve an address such as:`http://internal1` (provided that it exists)? If yes, how would it do that?

Comment: In other words, why does a proxy not see internal addresses?

Comment: "Extneral to you local network" as in, 'outside', or 'not a part of', your local network. If it was internal to your network (or at least fully under your control) then yes, a proxy could be configured to also contact internal hosts.

Comment: So I mean: What is the technical definition of being external to a network?

Comment: [External](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/external): "situated or being outside something; acting or coming from without".

Comment: I know what external means. I am asking: What does external mean in networking. Assume there is a LAN N. For a given device D, what conditions are required for D to be inside N? I am asking this.

Comment: In other words, for example both my and your computer are connected to the Internet. So are we on the same network? Yes. Are we on the same local network? I guess not. So what conditions are needed to be on the same local network?

Comment: That is a very different question that what you originally asked.  For answers to this new question, take a look at these existing SU questions and answers: [What is the real difference between LAN and WAN?](http://superuser.com/questions/326939/what-is-the-real-difference-between-lan-and-wan), [What is the difference between a LAN and Intranet?](http://superuser.com/questions/957763/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lan-and-intranet), [What exactly is a “network boundary?”](http://superuser.com/questions/984214/what-exactly-is-a-network-boundary)

Comment: Read that question but couldn't understand. Will post a new question.

Comment: If you do, please include the research you have done in already, and point out exactly what's confusing you.

Comment: Note that if there are one or more routers between any two devices, they are not in the same network (LAN). Network = LAN. the Internet is not a network, it is an "Internetwork" of connected LANs. Two devices on the internet iff and only if there are no routers between them.